# How to erase line if entry it doesn't match variable

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to make a program where you have to sign in with a password. If the password is incorrect it is supposed to erase the line so you can try again. Instead it just makes new lines. Any ideas on how to make this work?

```
cout << "--Bank Account Database--\n";
string password = "wfadmin";
string pwentry;
int entryCount = 0;
while (pwentry != password) {
    if (entryCount == 0) {
        string login = "\n\n\nEnter your password: ";
        cout << login;
        getline(cin, pwentry);
        cout << string(login.length(), '\b');
        entryCount++;
    }
    else {
        string login = "\nIncorrect. Try again.\n\nEnter your password: ";
        cout << login;
        getline(cin, pwentry);
        cout << string(login.length(), '\b');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done.
However, I do not know of a portable way of doing it.
The reason for that is that echoing of `stdin` is a [console property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-high-level-input-and-output-functions#code-try-0), and not part of the C++ standard.

There is a library designed to address that problem: [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html)
Beyond that, your loop can be simplified quite a bit. (See: [ideone](https://ideone.com/dPlpNy))

If there is a portable solution, I'm really interested to know. I spent about 5 hours looking around, and this was the best I got.